# $Y_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k 2^{-k}$ converges to $Y \in \ uniform(-1,1)$

Tags: probability-theory

If $X_k \in Ber\{-1,1\}$ and I let $Y_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k 2^{-k}$. How can I prove that $Y_n \to Y$ weak, where $Y$ is uniform on $(-1,1)$?

Comment: Check $F_{Y_n}$, it is incorrect. What for $x=-0.5$?

Comment: YEs, you are right! It is, then my guess is that there might be a better way to show the weak convergence? @NCh

Comment: Maybe one could show that $E[h(Y_n)] \to E[h(Y)]$ for all bounded and continuous $h$. @NCh

Comment: Doubt that it is possible. See answer below.

Comment: To use characteristic function is another choice.

Comment: @JGWang Would you like to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider few first r.v.'s
$$Y_1=\begin{cases}-\frac12& \text{ w.p. }\frac12\cr \hphantom{-}\frac12& \text{ w.p. } \frac12\end{cases}$$
The CDF of $Y_1$ looks like
$$
F_{Y_1}(x)=\begin{cases}0, & x<-\frac12 \cr \frac12, & -\frac12\leqslant x < \frac12 \cr 1, & x\geqslant \frac12
\end{cases}
$$
The maximal absolute distance of this CDF from the CDF of Uniform $(-1,1)$ distribution is reached at points $x=\pm\frac12$ and is equal to $\frac14$.
$$Y_2=\begin{cases}-\frac34& \text{ w.p. } \frac14\cr -\frac14& \text{ w.p. } \frac14\cr \hphantom{-}\frac14& \text{ w.p. } \frac14\cr\hphantom{-}\frac34& \text{ w.p. } \frac14\end{cases}
$$
The CDF of $Y_2$ looks like
$$
F_{Y_2}(x)=\begin{cases}0, & x<-\frac34 \cr \frac14, & -\frac34\leqslant x < -\frac14 \cr\frac12, & -\frac14\leqslant x < \frac14 \cr \frac34, & \frac14\leqslant x < \frac34 \cr 1, & x\geqslant \frac34
\end{cases}
$$
The maximal absolute distance of this CDF from the CDF of Uniform $(-1,1)$ distribution is reached at points $x=\pm\frac34$, $x=\pm\frac14$ and is equal to $\frac18$.

With equal probabilities $\frac1{2^n}$ r.v. $Y_n$ takes any value from the set
$$Y_n\in \left\{\pm\frac{1}{2^n},\pm\frac{3}{2^n},\pm\frac{5}{2^n},\ldots,\pm\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\right\}$$
The CDF of $Y_n$ is stepwise function of discrete uniform distribution with equal jumps by $\frac{1}{2^n}$. The distance of this CDF from CDF of Uniform $(-1,1)$ distribution is uniformly bounded by $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$
$$
\left|F_{Y_n}(x)-F_{U}(x)\right|\leq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
$$
The maximal absolute distance of this CDF from the CDF of Uniform $(-1,1)$ distribution is reached at points $x=\pm\frac{k}{2^n}$ and is equal to $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Writing the characteristic function of random variable $Z$ by $\phi_Z(t)=\mathsf{E}[e^{itZ}]$, easy to find that
\begin{align}
\phi_{X_k}(t)&=\mathsf{E}[e^{iX_kt}]=\frac12(e^{it}+e^{-it})=\cos t,\\
\phi_{X_k2^{-k}}(t)&=\cos\Bigl(\frac t{2^k}\Bigr)=\frac{\sin(t/2^{k-1})}{2\sin(t/2^k)},\\
\phi_{Y_n}(t)&=\prod_{k=1}^n\phi_{X_k2^{-k}}(t)=\frac{\sin t}{2^n\sin(t/2^n)},\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_{Y_n}(t)&=\frac{\sin t}{t}=\phi_Y(t).\qquad (Y\stackrel{\text{dist.}}=U(-1,1))
\end{align} 
Using the inverse limit theorem of characteristic functions we find that
$$ Y_n\stackrel{\text{dist.}}{\longrightarrow}Y\qquad \text{as }\; n\to\infty.$$
Futhermore, by the Polya theorem we have
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_x|F_{Y_n}(x)-F_Y(x)|=0.$$